# Installing Cassandra on Vagrant Centos using Puppet missing dsc22

Tags: cassandra, centos, vagrant, puppet

I'm new to puppet. I know that cassandra is missing from yum so I figured a puppet recipe would download and install it, but it seems like `locp/cassandra` is just trying to install it from yum. The recipe is supposed to work, but I don't see anything on https://github.com/locp/cassandra as to why it's not working for me or any thing I need to set up before it should work.

I used librarian-puppet to install the modules in puppet/modules.

**Error**

```
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Cassandra/File[/var/lib/cassandra/data]: Dependency Package[dsc22] has failures: true
```

**Vagrantfile**

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "puphpet/centos65-x64"

  config.vm.provision "puppet" do |p|
    p.module_path = "puppet/modules"
    p.manifests_path = "puppet/manifests"
    p.manifest_file = "site.pp"
  end
end
```

**puppet/manifests/site.pp**

```
class { 'cassandra':
  cluster_name    => 'foobar',
  listen_address  => "${::ipaddress}",
}
```

**puppet/Puppetfile**

```
forge 'https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com'

mod "locp/cassandra"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats probably because the repo is not configured (see [here](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.2/cassandra/install/installRHEL.html))

Add the following to your `site.pp` and make sure to add a `require` on it in your cassandra class

```
class repo {
  yumrepo { "datastax":
    descr          => "DataStax Repo for Apache Cassandra",
    baseurl        => "http://rpm.datastax.com/community",
    gpgcheck       => "0",
    enabled        => "1";
  } 
}

class { 'cassandra':
  cluster_name    => 'foobar',
  listen_address  => "${::ipaddress}",
  require         => Yumrepo["datastax"],
}

include repo
include cassandra
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I wish it said something about that. I tried your solution but I get Could not find dependency Yumrepo[datastax] for Class[Cassandra]

Comment: weird I have exactly copy/paste the pp file and it was working for me. just adding the include that I did not have before. can you go to /etc/yum.repos.d/ to see if the repo has been added ?

Comment: With the includes it adds the repo and installs cassandra ¯\_(ツ)_/¯.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the `cassandra::datastax_repo` class.  To incorporate that into the answer provided by @Frédéric-Henri, one could do the following:

```rb
class { 'cassandra::datastax_repo': } ->
class { 'cassandra':
    cluster_name   => 'foobar',
    listen_address => "${::ipaddress}"
}
```